# different apps with common code replaces the previous app

Tags: android

I am working on a project, which actually builds 2 different apps, but with common source. I have created 2 different AndroidManifest files for each project. however, the build works perfectly, but they both cant be installed together. If I install 1 app the previous gets removed. How can I make sure both the app can be installed at the same time?

Comment: the app package declared in your manifest have to be different. Could you post you manifests?

Comment: @buzeeg oh is it so. but after changing package name in manifest would i also need to change the package names in source.

Comment: no. You should use gradle Build Types (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) to create two apps with the same activity code. See how Cyril Mottier is doing it here : https://plus.google.com/u/0/118417777153109946393/posts/EATUmhntaCQ

Answer (score 0):

in your AndroidManifest.xml package should be different.

And your main activity declared in the manifest should match that same package.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Build Types](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) fonctionality of Gradle. Debug package is replaced at build time to be able to have two apps.

See how Cyril Mottier is doing it in [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/118417777153109946393/posts/EATUmhntaCQ).